# ЧПУ для кастомной таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Есть кастомная таксономия portfolio-category.
Сейчас url страницы таксономии выглядит следующим образом: http://site/portfolio/?portfolio-category=dlja-detej
А нужно http://site/portfolio/portfolio-category/dlja-detej

http://site/portfolio - это архивная страница

Как добиться такого?

Comment: Включить ЧПУ. Если не поможет - показать код (исправить вопрос, а не в комментах!) которым  сделана таксономия